# Is the exterior measure of a closed cube in $\mathbb{R^n}$ equal to the volume of it?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Is the exterior measure of a closed cube in $\mathbb{R^n}$  equal to the volume of it?  I think it is true but i have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: The answer is yes. The proof depends on how exactly you define exterior measure. Exterior measure is defined using coverings by open rectangles, sometimes closed rectangles, sometimes rectangles, sometimes cubes. All this definitions produce the same (Lebesgue) measure, although the proof is quite  tedious

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since a closed cube in $\Bbb R^n$ is of the form $\prod_{j=1}^n[a_j,b_j]$ and the outer measure of the closed cube is equal to $\prod_{j=1}^n(b_j-a_j)$, which is the volume. To check it, consider a decreasing sequence of open sets, and see if you can prove it from there. If you get stuck, let me know and I'll help you out after a while (or others may step in and guide you through).